# create-react-app-ts styled-component ThemProvider can't not be named

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, styled-components

I'm starting to use React with Typescript, I has init with `create-react-app` and `create-react-app-ts`, then I config to implement styled-components as guide: 
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript

And the linter complains:

`Exported variable 'ThemeProvider' has or is using name 'React.ComponentClass' from external module ".../@types/react/index" but cannot be named.`

Pls help me resolve this, thank you.

UPDATE

Here are the ts config and tslint files

**ts.config.json**

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build/lib",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "declaration": true
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "scripts",
        "acceptance-tests",
        "webpack",
        "jest",
        "src/setupTests.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.test.ts",
        "config",
        "dist"
      ]
    }
```

**tslint.json**

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint-react"],
  "rules": {
    "align": [true, "parameters", "arguments", "statements"],
    "ban": false,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [true, "check-space"],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": false,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [true, "spaces"],
    "interface-name": [true, "never-prefix"],
    "jsdoc-format": true,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "jsx-no-multiline-js": false,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [true, 120],
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "public-before-private",
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "log",
      "error",
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": true,
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],

    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [true, "always"],
    "switch-default": true,

    "trailing-comma": [false],

    "triple-equals": [true, "allow-null-check"],
    "typedef": [true, "parameter", "property-declaration"],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      "ban-keywords",
      "check-format",
      "allow-leading-underscore",
      "allow-pascal-case"
    ],
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-module",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type",
      "check-typecast"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your `tsconfig` , `tslint` ? can you provide those details as well...

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar  I updated my `tsconfig` and `tslint`